# Tikz: Different positioning behavior when using scrbook or book

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, document-classes, books, scrbook

when embedding my tikz images into different types of document-classes, I experience some very annoying differences. I have provided the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[
]{book}           
%]{scrbook}           
\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [rounded corners, fill=green!10] (-4,0) node [anchor=north west]{xXxXxXxXxXxXx} rectangle (4,-3);
    \node[draw] (n1)  { node 1};
    \node[below of=n1, draw] (n2)  { node 1};
    \node[below right of=n2, draw] (n3)  { node 1};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

When using `book` I get:

[image]

But with `scrbook` I get:

[image]

Unfortunately I am forced to use both classes of documents for the tikz pictures. How can I get rid of the displacement? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When running your example, the `book` class outputs

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-08-07>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo))
```

Note that it tells you it is using a 10pt font. With `scrbook` on the other hand:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-08-07>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbook.cls
Document Class: scrbook 2020/07/22 v3.31 KOMA-Script document class (book)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo)
```

See that it uses 11pt by default?

Different font sizes lead to different widths of the text so you should use the same font size to produce equal images.

Comment: +1 You are right.

Comment: Thank you so much! I use now `\documentclass[11pt]{book}` and I get the same images for both document classes.